# How does template argument deduction works recursively?

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading this article : http://accu.org/index.php/journals/409 . Let's take a simple example :

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T& param){}
```

and call to above function like `foo("String")` . Now how does deduction works recursively? . What I understood was deduction works something like this :

Type of Arg =  `const char[6]` and type of parameter is `T&` ->
so `T` must be -> `T1[]` -> which makes Parameter like `T1 (&) []`
-> now `T1` must of `const char` -> which makes Parameter like `const char (&)[]` .

Am I right path? Thanks

P.S -> I recently started learning c++ and programming, so is it ok if I learn cores of language first with examples rather than paying my attention to projects or huge algorithms? Thanks

Comment: If you're just starting to learn to program in C++ then you don't really need to know all those details.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Curiosity is a good enough reason to want to know about those details.

Comment: @VincentSavard It can also make you miss the forest because all you see is a lot of trees. Knowing the gritty details is good when one want to do advanced things, not so much when one is just starting out learning a new language.

Comment: @VincentSavard It is good enough reason to want, it isn't a good enough reason to actually know.  Imagine someone learning how to cook wanting to know how quantum mechanics leads to eggs going white when heated.  Great thing to be curious about, but still the wrong question to ask if you want to learn how to cook, let alone how to start cooking.  ;)  (and yes, QM->egg whitening is a bit of a stretch analogy.  But the chemistry of how it works is a pretty direct analogy: some advanced use of cooking requires learning that chemistry.  Learning to cook an egg does not.)

Comment: @Yakk, I feel like your chemistry example is a bit of a stretch. There is no quantum mechanics involved in whitening, it's the case of simple protein denaturation :)

Comment: @SergeyA Everything is quantum mechanics (well, and relativity) as far as we can tell.  ;)  You can model chemistry using QM (well, in theory: in practice, intractable beyond simple examples).

Comment: @Yakk: Bit of a stretch is severely understating your analogy, it isn't even close to a good one. It's normal to have questions during the learning process and it's okay to be curious about it. If the explanation is too hard to understand and this stage, then OP can come back later in his learning process. Just because it won't immediately be useful or understood doesn't mean he can't at least ask about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template deduction does not work recursively, at least in conventional sense of the term 'recursion'. (I feel you are using the term incorrectly). The actual deduction is rather straightforward. 
In this particular case, `T&` is `const char(&) [6]` (as you correctly pointed out), which means T is `const char[6]`.